# Angular 10 - NewComponent is not a known element

Tags: angular

Good morning!

I have set up a new angular 10 project. Right know it uses RouteLink to move among 3 routes /dashboard, /movies, and /characters, through clicking a button on a mat-toolbar in the app component.

This works fine and as expected. Now, I want to create a component named movie-card, which is part of what will be shown in the /movies route.

I generate the component in a new folder, create a movies.module.ts which declares and exports that component. After that, I import that module in app.modules.ts.

Then I go to movies.component.html, and after "movies works!", which is the default after generation, I write

> <app-movie-card></app-movie-card>

which is the proper selector name.

I think I have done every step right, however the mythical error shows:

```
1. If 'app-movie-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-movie-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3 <app-movie-card></app-movie-card>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/screens/movies/movies.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MoviesComponent.
```

Now, is there something I did wrong?? [Here is my repository,](https://github.com/emaestromartinez/elmar-wars/tree/develop) it is pushed with the error, on develop branch.

Thank you very much and sorry for this often asked question, I have spend too many hours on this :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot to declare MoviesComponent in movies.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieCardComponent } from '../../components/movie-card/movie-card.component';
import { MoviesComponent } from './movies.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [MovieCardComponent, MoviesComponent],
  declarations: [MovieCardComponent, MoviesComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class MoviesModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks man that was totally it... I can't believe I didn't know something so basic! How can I pick your answer as the "Solution"?

Comment: As a sidenote, try to use route-level code splitting (= 1 module per page). It will make sure you don't load unnecessary modules just because they're used in another page from the same module. So when generating a page: `ng g module edit --module person --route people`. When generating a component you can easily use `ng g c Editor --module components --export`. It will setup everything correctly.